# Unable to execute test method from mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing unit test for methods to find banks near my location.
I mocked the class and tried to call the methods.
But, control is not going to method to execute it.
Below is unit test case.

```
@Test
public void testFindBanksByGeo() {

    String spatialLocation = "45.36134,14.84400";
    String Address = "Test Address";
    String spatialLocation2 = "18.04706,38.78501";

    // 'SearchClass' is class where 'target' method resides
    SearchClass searchClass = Mockito.mock(SearchClass.class);
    BankEntity bank = Mockito.mock(BankEntity.class);

    // 'findAddressFromGeoLocation' and 'getGeo_location' to be mocked. They are called within 'target' method
    when(searchClass.findAddressFromGeoLocation(anyString())).thenReturn(Address);
    when(bank.getGeo_location()).thenReturn(spatialLocation2);

    // 'writeResultInJson' is void method. so needed to 'spy' 'SearchClass' 
    SearchClass spy = Mockito.spy(SearchClass.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).writeResultInJson(anyObject(), anyString());

    //This is test target method called. **Issue is control is not going into this method**
    SearchedBanksEntity searchBanksEntity = searchClass.findNearbyBanksByGeoLocation(spatialLocation, 500);

    assertNull(searchBankEntity);
}
```

What i have tried is also calling the real method on it,

```
Mockito.when(searchClass.findNearbyBanksByGeoLocation(anyString(), anyDouble())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

This calls real method but the methods i mocked above, are executing like real one. Means 'mocked methods' are not returning what i asked them to return.

So, what wrong i am doing here ?
why method is not executing?

Comment: `searchClass` is a mock, what you are trying to achieve is strange

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But i am new to Mockito. just calling it strange won't help me to grow. Rather mention what is wrong so that user can wrk on it.

Comment: could you share the relevant portion of code you are writing junit for?

Answer (score 0):

The method is not getting called because you are calling it on a mock. You should call the method on an actual object.

Or you could use something like this before invoking the method.

```
Mockito.when(searchClass.findNearbyBanksByGeoLocation(Mockito.eq(spatialLocation), Mockito.eq(500))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

But I think this is not the way you should write the test. You shouldn't be mocking SearchClass in the first place. Instead there would be a dependency in SearchClass which  gets you the address and geo location. You should be mocking that particular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's say we have this code:

```
class Foo {
    // has a setter
    SomeThing someThing;

    int bar(int a) {
       return someThing.compute(a + 3);
    }
}
```

We want to test `Foo#bar()`, but there's a dependency to `SomeThing`, we can then use a mock:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
class FooTest {
    @Mock // Same as "someThing = Mockito.mock(SomeThing.class)"
    private SomeThing someThing,

    private final Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        foo = new Foo(); // our instance of Foo we will be testing
        foo.setSomeThing(someThing); // we "inject" our mocked SomeThing
    } 

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        when(someThing.compute(anyInt()).thenReturn(2); // we define some behavior
        assertEquals(2, foo.bar(5)); // test assertion
        verify(someThing).compute(7); // verify behavior.
    } 
}
```

Using a mock we are able to avoid using a real `SomeThing`.

Some reading:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html
- https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki